# How can I check attribute existings by Elementtree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need to check certain attributes for existence. Like:

```py
if "blah-blah-blah" is None:
    print "there is no such attribute"
else:
    print "The attribute exists"
```

Comment: Okay "blah-blah-blah" makes no sense... The syntax isn't even Python and I can't see any relation to Elementtree - **please clarify this**

Comment: @Jon Why is the syntax not Python? Except for "blah-blah-blah" which is not a valid name. Edit: right, the missing colon after `else`...

Comment: Do you have to verify if there is certain attribute in some specific element, or whether the attribute is set in _any_ element? Could you post an example of what you are trying to do? An example of the input XML doc? Also, an example of the expected output?

Comment: And not sure I should bother mentioning, `whatever == None`, should be written `whatever is None`

Answer (score 36):

`Element` objects have all the attributes in the [`attrib`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) dict.

```py
if 'blah' not in elem.attrib:
   print "there is no such attribute"
```

Comment: Where can i set the tag? 
What is 'blah'? blah == attrib?

Comment: @user1464922 I gave the best answer I was able to given how you stated the question. How to set the tag is a different question, and the answer will depend on what you need to do with the XML document. I suggest reading the documentation I link to and also a short guide on [how  to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).